# HTTPS request from Docker container to LAN IP fails, but curl works

Tags: node.js, docker, https

I'm developing for an embedded device which is accessible on my LAN. I want to make a request to its API from inside a Docker container which contains my dev environment.

The device is exposed at `https://172.16.1.92` (it does not have a proper HTTPS certificate, of course). I can successfully visit this URL in my browser and everything works as it should.

If I run this:

```
docker run -it --rm node:5 curl --insecure https://172.16.1.92/api
```

I see the expected result (a JSON object).

However, after writing a quick JS test script:

```js
var https = require('https');

https.request({
  host: '172.16.1.92',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api',
  timeout: 5 * 1000,
  rejectUnauthorized: false, // for the lack of certificate
}, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

And running it:

```
docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`:/code -w /code node:5 node test.js
```

I get this error after several seconds:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:206:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:298:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
```

I'm confused - why can I access the URL fine using curl, but not using node's `https` library?

---

If I run `nmap -sP 172.16.1.*` on my host, I see this line:

```
Nmap scan report for WRN_002258.lan (172.16.1.92)
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (vendor)
```

But if I install `nmap` inside the Docker container and run the same command, I see this instead:

```
Nmap scan report for 172.16.1.92
Host is up (0.0032s latency).
```

Is that significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code performs a TCP handshake with the HTTP Server, but doesn't send data over it, yet.

Modify your Node.js code to:

```
var https = require('https');

var req = https.request({
    host: '172.16.1.92',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api',
    timeout: 5 * 1000,
    rejectUnauthorized: false, // for the lack of certificate
}, function(res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
});

req.end()
```

You should read the documentation for [https.request()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) and documentation for [http.request()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). Once you do that, you will also end up reading the documentation for [request.end()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback)

For a TL;DR moment: `request.end()` finishes sending the request.

Comment: Wow, that was really dumb of me. I always forget that request() just constructs the request. Thanks for having the patience to answer!